# R: Remove rows with fewer than certain threshold non-zero values

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I would like to know how to remove rows from a data frame that have fewer than (let's say 5) non-zero entries.

The closest I've come is:

```
length(which(df[1,] > 0)) >= 5
```

but how to apply this to the whole data frame and drop the ones that are FALSE? Is there a function similar to the COUNTIF() function in excel that I can apply here?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You meant `>=` and not `=>` right?

Answer (score 3):

You can use boolean values in `rowSums` and in `[`:

```
 df[ rowSums(df > 0) >= 5, ]
```

There are 3 steps hidden in this expression:

- expression `df > 0` produces a matrix with values TRUE where element > 0
- Function `rowSums` returns number of nonzero elements for every line (when summing it treats values TRUE as 1 and FALSE as 0)
- finally `[` selects only lines where the number of non-zero elements >= 5

Comment: Thank you for responding, but I think you misunderstood my question. I am not looking for the sum of the entries, but rather the number of entries that are non-zero. For example, if a row contained 0 0 0 5 2 0 I would want it removed. Similar to applying the COUNTIF() function in excel

Comment: Note that the rowSums is not applied on the entries but on the boolean matrix which is produced by expression `df > 5`. The result is a boolean vector which is used to filter-out the lines with less then 5 non-zero elements. It should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a for-loop.

We first create a matrix of zero's and one's to test our code. Row 2 has to be excluded because it has less than 5 non-zero values.

In the loop we count the number of non-zero values per row, and assign TRUE if this is less than 5 (FALSE otherwise). The vector named 'drop' holds the information for which row is TRUE then FALSE. In the final step, we exclude those rows for which drop==TRUE.

```
mat <- matrix(c(1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1), nrow=3, ncol=5)
mat

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1
[2,]    1    0    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1    1    1

drop <- NULL
for(i in 1:NROW(mat)){
  count.non.zero <- sum(mat[i,]!=0, na.rm=TRUE)
  drop <- c(drop, count.non.zero<5)
} 

mat[!drop==TRUE,]

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1    1    1
```

NOTE: `na.rm==TRUE` allows this script to work when your data contains missing values.